# Having an element list the text of all the elements its connected to

Tags: visio

I'm trying to have a very simple to read diagram of a weekly routine.
For that I had set up a simple calendar like this, to one side:

```
| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
----------------------------------------------------
|   9:00 |    9:00 |      9:00 |     9:00 |   9:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  10:00 |   10:00 |     10:00 |    10:00 |  10:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
|  11:00 |   11:00 |     11:00 |    11:00 |  11:00 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

An a list of my activities in another side

```
|       Gym |
-------------
|    School |
-------------
| Breakfast |
```

Now, if I were to connect those three activities to the first diagram there'll be arrows all over the place and would be very hard to read.
So, what I actually need is that when one activity is connected to a time element, that the time element were to display the text of the activity its connected to.

So I end up with something like this:

```
| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
----------------------------------------------------
|   9:00 |    9:00 |      9:00 |     9:00 |   9:00 |
|    Gym | Breakft |       Gym |  Breakft |    Gym |
----------------------------------------------------
|  10:00 |   10:00 |     10:00 |    10:00 |  10:00 |
|Breakft |  School | Breakfast |   School | Breakf |
----------------------------------------------------
|  11:00 |   11:00 |     11:00 |    11:00 |  11:00 |
| School |     Gym |    School |      Gym |    Gym |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I tried lots of templates and watched many tutorials about Visio on youtube but I couldn't find how to do it, surely there is a way.

Comment: Hi, Maximilliano! Why you need do this with MS Visio?

Comment: How about trying a spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey. I really like Visio interface, that's why I wanted to do it with it if possible.

Comment: My weekly routine is far more complex than the example I put, with dozens of pieces. A spreadsheet would be too slow as I'll have to set up every cell independently.

Comment: @MaximilianoCorbo Do you think Visio would be any different? Doing this in Visio will be far more complicated than in a spreadsheet. If a spreadsheet is too slow for this task then you need a new computer.